# Server.Execute with a fixed path

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to implement `server.execute()` via an include from a virtual functions library (`<!-- #include virtual="lib/functions.asp"-->`) that I can call on from any subfolder in the system. I am trying to implement a new function that should exist on all pages in our system, and it would be virtually unfeasible to go in and add it manually to every single page. And I need it to be implemented in such a way that it does not interfere with the code on any page which is why I am doing it as a `server.execute()` in a virtual lib that I know already exists everywhere in the system.

For example:

```
'location of routine.asp = https://example.com/admin/routine/routine.asp

Server.Execute("routine/routine.asp")
'Will work if I add the virtual lib from an ASP-page in the admin subfolder, but not if I call it from another subfolder

Server.Execute("https://example.com/admin/routine/routine.asp")
'Does not work, because server.execute can't handle that kind of fixed path
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525849(v%3Dvs.90)) clearly states that colons and double-slashes are not allowed, but I can't figure out how I can make sure the execution of the file happens no matter where in the system it's called from.

**Question:** How can I make `server.execute(path)`'s path handle a fixed path, or change the path dynamically to make sure I can always target the file correctly?

Comment: Can you not just use `Server.Execute("/admin/routine/routine.asp")`?

Comment: But of course! It was too simple. Couldn't see the forest for the trees and all that. Cheers, @Lankymart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an absolute path make sure you are using an absolute path (full path from the root).

Think you simply need to specify the absolute path explicitly;

```vb
Server.Execute("/admin/routine/routine.asp")
```